# Laravel - Prevent from create empty key in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a table where I keep all the settings that will be used on the website, they are saved in the cache, I'm trying to upload the favicon, however when uploading the image the favicon row is updated and an empty key value with the temp path is created at the same time, how can I solve this?

[image]
You can see the empty field in the image...

Route

```
Route::put('/', ['as' => 'setting.update', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminConfiguracoesController@update']);
```

Model

```php
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'settings';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['value'];
}
```

Controller

```php
class AdminConfiguracoesController extends AdminBaseController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(SettingRepository $repository){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Factory $cache)
    {
        $settings = $request->except('_method', '_token');

        $this->repository->update($settings);

        $cache->forget('settings');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Repository

```php
class SettingRepository{
    private $settings;

    public function __construct(Setting $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function update($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            foreach ($key as $name => $value)
            {
                if( $name == "website_favicon" ){
                    $imageName = $key['website_favicon']->getClientOriginalName();

                    $this->update($name, asset('public/images/website/'.$imageName));

                    $key['website_favicon']->move(
                        base_path() . '/public/images/website/', $imageName
                    );
                } else{
                    $this->update($name, $value);
                }
            }
        }

        $setting = $this->settings->firstOrCreate(['name' => $key]);
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }

    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->settings->lists('value', 'name')->all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate! Your repository shouldn't be responsible for uploading the favicon, but anyways... Does the favicon exist on your server after uploading it?

Comment: @tommy yes, I move it to the specific folder, the only problem is the empty register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a missing return statement after the foreach loop in your repository. The code after the loop will be executed. `$key` is an array and `$value` is the temp value of the uploaded file, which will be set inside the loop.

As I mentioned in my comment, you shouldn't use the repository to upload files. Do it in your controller instead:

`AdminConfiguracoesController.php`

```php
class AdminConfiguracoesController extends AdminBaseController
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(SettingRepository $repository)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Factory $cache)
    {
        $settings = $request->except('_method', '_token', 'website_favicon');

        if ($request->hasFile('website_favicon'))
        {
            $this->uploadImage($request->file('website_favicon'), 'website_favicon');
            $cache->forget('website_favicon');
        }

        $this->repository->update($settings);

        $cache->forget('settings');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    private function uploadImage(UploadedFile $image, $key)
    {
        $image->move(public_path('images/website'), $image->getClientOriginalName());

        $this->repository->update($key, $image->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

`SettingRepository.php`

```php
class SettingRepository
{

    private $settings;

    public function __construct(Setting $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function update($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            foreach ($key as $name => $value)
            {
                $this->update($name, $value);
            }

            return; // This was missing!
        }

        $setting = $this->settings->firstOrCreate(['name' => $key]);
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }

    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->settings->lists('value', 'name')->all();
    }
}
```

You can refactor this even further to use a Job that uploads the image, but this would be overkill for now.